# Single Page App back-button history with exceptions?

Tags: javascript, html, url, html5-history

I am working on a single page app and I've ran into an issue with HTML5's history API, or rather the behavior is quite expected, I just don't know how to work around it.

We are not using any frameworks, so please keep in mind, native only.

**TL;DR: How to prevent the `window.onpopstate` handler from firing when the history state changes only the `#hash` not the `location.url` since all the content is already present, just the hash changed from `#something` to having no hash (initial pageload)**

Let's say we are on a homepage of this app. We navigate to some page, lets say **Page 1** (this page loads up via AJAX and pretty much replaces almost the entire homepage) as well as uses `history.pushState()` to make an entry so that we can navigate back to it. Now on Page 1, we have some anchors like so:

`<a href="#content1">` `<a href="#content2">`

These obviously point to certain parts of Page1 that are div's with mentioned IDs. What they also do however is, make a history entry. So let's say our navigation route went like this:

Homepage > Page1 > #content1 > #content2.

Now when we click the back-button, it goes from #content2 > #content1, which is fine, since the `window.onpopstate` handler (see below) is designed to only fire it's appropriate AJAX calls in case we made a `history.pushState` call with a specific state object. However, when the user clicks the back button a second time going:

#content1 > Page1

**This is where the issue arises.** 
Namely, the `history.pushState()` created when Page1 was clicked indeed has the necessary state object for it to fire an AJAX call. And a reload of the content happens, even though all the content is already present and all we've been doing was navigating through the page's anchors.

How would I prevent this?
I tried seeing if `location.hash` has the info of the previous state in the `window.onpopstate`'s event, however the location is already updated once this event fires, so I cannot check to see if location remains the same and intercept the AJAX call.

How do I differentiate between a #hash history state and a proper state switch?

**windows.onpopstate handler:**

```
//state.ExeSce makes sure that this was indeed a history.pushState that we want
if (event.state && event.state["ExeSce"]) {
    var params = new Map(window.location.search.substring(1).split("&").map(function (element) {
        return element.split("=");
    }));
    var tempObj = {};
    var process = event.state['process'];
    var activity = event.state['activity'];;
    params.forEach(function (value, key) {
        tempObj[key] = value;
    });
    ExecuteScenario('POST', process, activity, tempObj);
    //This fires the AJAX call function with all the necessary data.
}
```

**EDIT:** Also, while on the topic of back-forth with #hash in url, why does the browser not scroll to the div's with #hash id's when we go back/forward through history? I had to manually element.scrollIntoView() them on popstate.

Comment: Far too much to read

Comment: K tl;dr incoming